# Linear space, system of linearly independent vectors - conclusions

Tags: linear-algebra

$X$ is linear space, $\dim X = n$. Vectors $x_1,...,x_k\in X$ are linearly independent.  Then:
**a.** $k \le n$
**b.** there is exists some base of $X$ such that this base contains $x_1,...,x_k$
**c.** if $k > 2$ then $span(x_1,x_2) \cap span(x_3,..,x_k)=\{0\}$

**My approach:**
**a.** It is true. In other case vectors are not linearly independent.
**b.** It is true - Steiniz's theorem.
**c.** It is true, but I can't prove it. Can you help me with it ?
Tell me please, if my explanations and answers are ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) and b) seem fine. Note that a) also follows from Steinitz' Lemma.

As for c), suppose that $v\in span(x_{1},x_{2})\cap span(x_{3},\ldots,x_{k})$. Then we can write $v=c_{1}x_{1} + c_{2}x_{2}$ and $v=c_{3}x_{3}+\cdots+c_{k}x_{k}$ for constants $c_{1},\ldots,c_{k}$.

So
$c_{1}x_{1}+c_{2}x_{2}=c_{3}x_{3}+\cdots+c_{k}x_{k}$,  hence $c_{1}x_{1}+c_{2}x_{2}-c_{3}x_{3}-\cdots-c_{k}x_{k}=0$. By linear independence of $x_{1},\ldots,x_{k}$, we get that $c_{1}=\cdots=c_{k}=0$. So $v=0$.

Hence $span(x_{1},x_{2})\cap span(x_{3},\ldots,x_{k})=\{0\}$.